# Special characters in property name

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, special-characters

In my Application a webservice will return a json

```
{
    "UserDetails": [
      {
        "UserId": "57",
        "EmailId": "prasant@xyz.com",
        "UserName": "Prasant",
        "TimezoneMins": "330",
        "CustomLogo": "",
        "IsExecutive": "True",
        "HasNTID": "1",
        "Org_Id": "1",
        "Org_Name": "Summit",
        "Designation": null,
        "Location": null,
        "Location_Name": "",
        "WsVersion": "V5.1.0",
        "CallMe": "FALSE",
        "GPS": "FALSE",
        "Feedback_IM&SR": "NULL",
        "RPT_Widgets_Access": "False"
      }
    ]   }
```

Here i want to Deserialize this json into a class object. In which the class contains the properties same as the keys in json.

```
public class UserDetails
    {
        int? _userId;
        string _emailId;
        string _userName;
        int _timezoneMins;
        string _customLogo;
        string _isExecutive;
        int _hasNTID;
        int? _org_Id;
        string _org_Name;
        string _designation;
        int? _location;
        string _location_Name;
        string _feedback_IMSR;
        string _rPT_Widgets_Access;
        public string Feedback_IM&SR
        {
           get{return _feedback_IMSR;}
           set{_feedback_IMSR = value;}
        }

    }
```

Here the variable and property "Feedback_IM&SR" is having '&' character which is not allowed either in variable and Property names,but i need the value of that property.

Can anyone help me on this please.

Comment: Are you using any particular library to deserialize the json to your c# class?

Comment: Can you change `Feedback_IM&SR` to `Feedback_IM_AND_SR`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make class objects from json using following references

http://json2csharp.com/

Just paste your json string and it will generate C# class and properties inside that json.

Answer (score 19):

Use [Netwonsoft.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm):

```
var details = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDetails>(json);
```

For your class, you need to have attributes on your properties for the names:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Feedback_IM&SR")]
string _feedback_imsr { get; set; }
```

Now you can keep the JSON data having whatever names it wishes to, and have your C# class have another name for the property. And as part of your class, that would look like:

```
public class UserDetails
{
    int? _userId;
    string _emailId;
    string _userName;
    int _timezoneMins;
    string _customLogo;
    string _isExecutive;
    int _hasNTID;
    int? _org_Id;
    string _org_Name;
    string _designation;
    int? _location;
    string _location_Name;
    string _wsVersion;
    string _callMe;
    string _gPS;
    string _feedback_IMSR;
    string _rPT_Widgets_Access;
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Feedback_IM&SR")]
    public string Feedback_IMSR
    {
       get{return _feedback_IMSR;}
       set{_feedback_IMSR = value;}
    }
}
```

Comment: its fine with your answer,but i also want to know if i miss a property for any key in json will the deserialization throws any error?

Comment: for example i didnt written any property for gps will it throws any error or exception

Comment: @govardhan Interesting question! I've never tried that, perhaps test it out by commenting out a property in your C# class, I can't access an IDE right now :( I'd like to know!

Answer (score 8):

you can all each property however you want, but in the C# implelmentation write it down like this:

```
class UserDetails
{
   [JsonProperty ("Feedback_IM&SR")]
    public string FeedbackProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

If you the "JsonProperty" attribute above the property, the serializer will know that in the JSON, the property's name is the one stated in the attribute

Comment: I wrote it down on my own thank you very much, and why won't it compile?
it's a genuine question, and my answer is also completely fine,

Comment: Okay well that's good, it's just why your answer was downvoted. *Wasn't me!*

Comment: Then would you mine upvoting it? just lost 2 points for nothing!
I feel lame for asking to be honest, but your blame throwing got me down.
and it's ok man, we all make mistakes.

Comment: Sorry, if I was harsh, I upvoted it, your answer was fine.