# Access data in JSON C# Dynamic variable

Tags: c#, json, parsing

I am working with processing/consuming some data from: https://ashesescalation-api-tachyon.stardock.net/v1/products/2641/leaderboards/ladder/de5bfc9a-9092-4014-b52e-89151de42646?offset=0&count=2 (which can be opened easily in Firefox to view.)

I am able to access the data in C# by doing this:
data being the json data...

```
dynamic players = JArray.Parse(data);
var p = players[0];
Console.Write(p.personaName);
```

However I am having trouble accessing the part in the JSON data: "dataInteger" for example the "totalUnitsKilled."

```
p.dataInteger[0].totalUnitsKilled
```

That "p.dataInteger[0].totalUnitsKilled" doesn't work.

How can I access that data in C#?

Thank you very much for your help.

Warren

### [See image in visual studio 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWeq2.png)

### [See image in visual studio 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89u2F.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Special characters in property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38719368/special-characters-in-property-name)

Comment: Hi. I didn't create the rest api. I am trying to use it. So I can't change the source. I just want to know how to get for example the data inside "dataInteger" I can't figure out how.

Comment: take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON string is wrong.

```
[{"personaLadderId":"371eaf1c-4cfe-4873-af41-56e0cb9fcf91","rank":1,"personaId":"55834d01-13f3-445e-861f-0bc4769d87cc","personaName":"Amelie","avatarUrl":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg","avatarUrlSmall":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb.jpg","avatarUrlMedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_medium.jpg","avatarUrlLarge":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/fe/fef49e7fa7e1997310d705b2a6158ff8dc1cdfeb_full.jpg","ladderType":"Ranked","ladderId":"de5bfc9a-9092-4014-b52e-89151de42646","seasonId":"fd7dd807-4ac2-40ec-8476-a4b2937f70af","bracketId":0,"bracketName":"Legendary","rankingScore":38,"secondaryScore":2054,"ruleTypeId":1,"wins":374,"losses":32,"ties":0,"tieStreak":0,"winStreak":8,"lossStreak":0,"longestTieStreak":0,"longestWinStreak":61,"longestLossStreak":3,"bracketMaxScore":0,"bracketScore":0,"updateDate":"2018-03-03T14:13:09.647Z","totalMatchesPlayed":406,"dataInteger":{"totalUnitsKilled ":92615,"totalTitansKilled":14,"totalTimePlayed":294676,"substrate-TotalGamesPlayed":127,"phC-TotalGamesPlayed":6,"lastReplayVersion":265301040,"replayUploadedCount":160}},{"personaLadderId":"f0dd3482-f057-44d6-a626-9c9389ad2583","rank":2,"personaId":"b53815ab-d753-4415-9ea6-03a4519c3222","personaName":"Rebellions","avatarUrl":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/b9/b9847c92d44896304cc2d673e1fbe7bc99af7f5b.jpg","avatarUrlSmall":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/b9/b9847c92d44896304cc2d673e1fbe7bc99af7f5b.jpg","avatarUrlMedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/b9/b9847c92d44896304cc2d673e1fbe7bc99af7f5b_medium.jpg","avatarUrlLarge":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/b9/b9847c92d44896304cc2d673e1fbe7bc99af7f5b_full.jpg","ladderType":"Ranked","ladderId":"de5bfc9a-9092-4014-b52e-89151de42646","seasonId":"fd7dd807-4ac2-40ec-8476-a4b2937f70af","bracketId":0,"bracketName":"Legendary","rankingScore":38,"secondaryScore":2049,"ruleTypeId":1,"wins":767,"losses":188,"ties":0,"tieStreak":0,"winStreak":3,"lossStreak":0,"longestTieStreak":0,"longestWinStreak":52,"longestLossStreak":6,"bracketMaxScore":0,"bracketScore":0,"updateDate":"2017-10-29T18:03:33.92Z","totalMatchesPlayed":955,"dataInteger":{"totalUnitsKilled ":293274,"totalTitansKilled":88,"totalTimePlayed":924881,"phC-TotalGamesPlayed":4,"substrate-TotalGamesPlayed":350,"lastReplayVersion":250285270,"replayUploadedCount":703}}]
```

There is a space in your json key name ("totalUnitsKilled ") which is ultimately converted to a variable name.

Correct your JSON key name will fix this issue. There are other keys with error as well.

You can check at http://json2csharp.com/. Wherever it is  "**invalid_name**", key name is wrong.

```
public class DataInteger
{
    public int __invalid_name__totalUnitsKilled  { get; set; }
    public int totalTitansKilled { get; set; }
    public int totalTimePlayed { get; set; }
    public int __invalid_name__substrate-TotalGamesPlayed { get; set; }
    public int __invalid_name__phC-TotalGamesPlayed { get; set; }
    public int lastReplayVersion { get; set; }
    public int replayUploadedCount { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string personaLadderId { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public string personaId { get; set; }
    public string personaName { get; set; }
    public string avatarUrl { get; set; }
    public string avatarUrlSmall { get; set; }
    public string avatarUrlMedium { get; set; }
    public string avatarUrlLarge { get; set; }
    public string ladderType { get; set; }
    public string ladderId { get; set; }
    public string seasonId { get; set; }
    public int bracketId { get; set; }
    public string bracketName { get; set; }
    public int rankingScore { get; set; }
    public int secondaryScore { get; set; }
    public int ruleTypeId { get; set; }
    public int wins { get; set; }
    public int losses { get; set; }
    public int ties { get; set; }
    public int tieStreak { get; set; }
    public int winStreak { get; set; }
    public int lossStreak { get; set; }
    public int longestTieStreak { get; set; }
    public int longestWinStreak { get; set; }
    public int longestLossStreak { get; set; }
    public int bracketMaxScore { get; set; }
    public int bracketScore { get; set; }
    public DateTime updateDate { get; set; }
    public int totalMatchesPlayed { get; set; }
    public DataInteger dataInteger { get; set; }
}
```

You can use JSON.Net attributes to define C# variables related to JSON key names. Check [this](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GenerateWithJsonNetAttributes.htm) for more details.

Your new class should look like:

```
public class DataInteger
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "totalUnitsKilled ")]
    public int totalUnitsKilled { get; set; }
    public int totalTitansKilled { get; set; }
    public int totalTimePlayed { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "substrate-TotalGamesPlayed")]
    public int substrateTotalGamesPlayed { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "phC-TotalGamesPlayed")]
    public int phCTotalGamesPlayed { get; set; }
    public int lastReplayVersion { get; set; }
    public int replayUploadedCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: why do you have to create the whole class? json result can be parsed by an object.

Comment: @JericCruz I just provide example for finding error. In json2csharp.com, you can create class and also check the result for any error in json key. It is logical  and smart use of that site.   This can not be a reason to down vote my answer. Provide some proper reason or remove downvote.

Comment: You can take a look in "How do I write a good answer?" link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @JericCruz Thanks. I will read again though I already did.  You can suggest if any changes are required in my answer. I will surely accept if it is good.

Answer (score 0):

Kinldy take a look at my comment in your question, base on that link you need to use `JsonProperty` to mapped the key that has special characters and manually named it based on your needs.

Anyways, you can do the following to achieved what you need.

1. Copy your link to http://json2csharp.com/
2. Copy the generated Quicktypes and paste it to your code.
3. Use `JsonProperty` to indicate attributes on your properties for the names and **manually rename** properties that contains **invalid_name**
4. And `DeserializeObject` the object.

Here is the code:

**Declare the classes from the generated quicktypes.**

```
public class DataInteger
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "totalUnitsKilled ")]
    public int totalUnitsKilled { get; set; }
    public int totalTitansKilled { get; set; }
    public int totalTimePlayed { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "substrate-TotalGamesPlayed")]
    public int SubstrateTotalGamesPlayed { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "phC-TotalGamesPlayed")]
    public int PHCTotalGamesPlayed { get; set; }
    public int lastReplayVersion { get; set; }
    public int replayUploadedCount { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string personaLadderId { get; set; }
    public int rank { get; set; }
    public string personaId { get; set; }
    public string personaName { get; set; }
    public string avatarUrl { get; set; }
    public string avatarUrlSmall { get; set; }
    public string avatarUrlMedium { get; set; }
    public string avatarUrlLarge { get; set; }
    public string ladderType { get; set; }
    public string ladderId { get; set; }
    public string seasonId { get; set; }
    public int bracketId { get; set; }
    public string bracketName { get; set; }
    public int rankingScore { get; set; }
    public int secondaryScore { get; set; }
    public int ruleTypeId { get; set; }
    public int wins { get; set; }
    public int losses { get; set; }
    public int ties { get; set; }
    public int tieStreak { get; set; }
    public int winStreak { get; set; }
    public int lossStreak { get; set; }
    public int longestTieStreak { get; set; }
    public int longestWinStreak { get; set; }
    public int longestLossStreak { get; set; }
    public int bracketMaxScore { get; set; }
    public int bracketScore { get; set; }
    public DateTime updateDate { get; set; }
    public int totalMatchesPlayed { get; set; }
    public DataInteger dataInteger { get; set; }
}
```

**Call the API (*Magic begins here*)**

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();

var link = $@"https://ashesescalation-api-tachyon.stardock.net/v1/products/2641/leaderboards/ladder/de5bfc9a-9092-4014-b52e-89151de42646?offset=0&count=2";

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(link);
var contents = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

//deserialized json result object...
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(contents);
foreach (var item in json)
{
    //deserialized again the item
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(Convert.ToString(item));
    //you can now access all the properties including dataInteger.
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(data.dataInteger.totalUnitsKilled));
    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(data.dataInteger.totalTitansKilled));
}
```

[image]

**Update:**

If you don't want to use strongly typed class you can do parsing using `JArray`

```
JArray jsonVal = JArray.Parse(contents) as JArray;
dynamic items = jsonVal;
foreach (dynamic item in items)
{
    var x = item.dataInteger;
    //you can access the fields inside dataInteger.
    Console.WriteLine(x["totalUnitsKilled "]);
    Console.WriteLine(x["phC-TotalGamesPlayed"]);
    Console.WriteLine(x["substrate-TotalGamesPlayed"]);
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to use not use the strongly typed class?

Comment: updated the answer to use `JArray` and to access the data by the keys indicated in the json

Comment: That looks so much smaller and easier.

Comment: @user1605822 glad it helps you out, but it would be great if you marked it as an answered.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by other users, there is a space in property name "totalUnitsKilled ", if you change it to "totalUnitsKilled". Below code will work fine:-

```
Console.WriteLine(p.dataInteger.totalUnitsKilled);
```